# How can we get commodity prices in R?

Tags: r, api, price, commodity

As the title, I know we can use `quantmod` package to get stock prices, but how can we retrieve commodity prices like Gold, Oil or Aggs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Quandl` package, here are some examples

```
Gold <- Quandl("LBMA/GOLD")
WTI <- Quandl("CHRIS/CME_CL1")
Corn <- Quandl("CHRIS/CME_C1")
```

You can go to their website for more information.

This is the page you can get ticker information.

https://www.quandl.com/collections/markets/crude-oil

Comment: Is there a way to bulk download all commodity prices (Metal, energy etc.) ? I went through Quandl but couldn't find a single source that contains everything